# Query Facebook using wildcards

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible? I already know how to do AND/OR queries (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674685/facebook-graph-api-search-rules), and I also want to be able to use wildcards. Can it be done without FQL, using only the /search path?

Comment: Doesn't the existing search endpoint take your inputs as substrings for a partial match? e.g. a search for 'new y' returns 'new york'?

Comment: I noticed that depends on the type of objects requested. For example, a query for pages does indeed regard it as a sub-string, but a query for users returns only exact matches.